# Sending mail in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, email, lumen

I've read a lot of guides and questions and answers on how to send mail using Lumen. I've tried a lot of these suggestions.

However, I still get this error:

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), 0 passed in /var/www/monitor/vendor/illuminate/support/Manager.php on line 88 and exactly 1 expected
```

Full stack trace [here](https://pastebin.com/X8vQmeEJ).

This is my controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

public function check() {
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    if ($response) {
        if ($this->isAlive($response->state)) {
            $user = new \stdClass();
            $user->email = '****@gmail.com';
            $user->name = 'Albert';
            Mail::raw('test', function($mail) use ($user) {
                $mail->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Test Subject');
            });
            // I've also tried Mail::send() but no luck
            echo 'System is fine';
        } else {
            echo 'System has issues';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error connecting';
    }
}
```

I have uncommented and added the following lines to my `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->withFacades();
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
```

I've got the following in my `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmailaddress@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mygmailpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: what statements do you have on line 88

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the mail manager depends on the mail configuration, and Lumen has not included the mail configuration by default since 5.1. If you are using Lumen > 5.1, you will need to add your own mail config file, and update your bootstrap file to load the configuration file.

First, create a `config` directory next to your `app` directory.

Next, add a `mail.php` file in your new `config` directory. You can copy the contents from the default Laravel install that matches the Lumen version you are using (for example, if you're using Lumen 5.4, just copy the `mail.php` config file from Laravel 5.4).

Finally, in your `bootstrap/app.php` file, load the configuration file:

```
$app->configure('mail');
```

I would put this line before you register your mail service provider, just to be safe.

Comment: This solved it. I'm now getting a timeout error, but atleast we are further than before. Thanks patricus!